# Concurrency with Hibernate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I found a lot of posts regarding this topic, but all answers were just links to documentations with no example code, i.e., how to use concurrency in practice.

My situation: I have an entity `House` with (for simplyfication) two attributes, `number` (the id) and `owner`. The database is initialized with 10 `Houses` with `number` 1-10 and `owner` always `null`.

I want to assign a new owner to the house with currently no owner, and the smallest `number`. My code looks like this:

```
@Transactional
void assignNewOwner(String newOwner) {
    //this is flagged as @Transactional too
    House tmp = houseDao.getHouseWithoutOwnerAndSmallestNumber();

    tmp.setOwner(newOwner);

    //this is flagged as @Transactional too
    houseDao.update(tmp);
}
```

For my understanding, although the `@Transactional` is used, the same `House` could be assigned twice to different owners, if two requests fetch the same empty `House` as `tmp`. How do I ensure this can not happen?

I know, including the update in the selection of the empty `House` would solve the issue, but in near future, I want to modify/work with the `tmp` object more.

Comment: The `houseDao.update(tmp);` is unnecessary, since `tmp` is a managed entity (you're in a transactional method). The changes will be persisted without needing a separate `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Optimistic**

If you add a version column to your entity / table then you could take advantage of a mechanism called Optimistic Locking. This is the most proficient way of making sure that the state of an entity has not changed since we obtained it in a transactional context.

Once you `createQuery` using the `session` you can then call `setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);`

Then, just  before the transaction is commited, the persistence provider would query for the current version of that entity and check whether it has been incremented by another transaction. If so, you would get an OptimisticLockException and a transaction rollback.

**Pessimistic**

If you do not version your rows, then you are left with pessimistic lockin which basically means that you phycically create a lock for queries entities on the database level and other transactions cannot read / update those certain rows.

You achieve that by setting this on the `Query` object:

`setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);`

or

`setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's pretty easy - at least in my opinion and I am going to abstract away of what `Hibernate` will generate when you say `Pessimistic/Optimistic`. You might think this is `SELECT FOR UPDATE` - but it's not always the case, MSSQL AFAIK does not have that...

These are `JPA` annotations and they guarantee some functionality, not the implementation.

Fundamentally they are entire different things - `PESSIMISTIC` vs `OPTIMISTIC` locking. When you do a pessimistic locking you sort of do a `synchronized block` at least logically - you can do whatever you want and you are safe within the scope of the transaction. Now, whatever the lock is being held for the `row, table or even page` is un-specified; so a bit dangerous. Usually database may escalate locks, MSSQL does that if I re-call correctly.

Obviously lock starvation is an issue, so you might think that `OPTIMISTIC` locking would help. As a side note, this is what `transactional memory is in modern CPU`; they use the same thinking process.

So optimistically locking is like saying - I will mark this row with an ID/Date, etc, then I will take a snapshot of that and work with it - before committing I will check if that Id has a changed. Obviously there is contention on that `ID`, but not on the data. If it has changed - abort (aka throw `OptimisticLockException`) otherwise commit the work.

The thing that bothers everyone IMO is that `OptimisticLockException` - how do you recover from that? And here is something you are not going to like - *it depends*. There are apps where a simple retry would be enough, there are apps where this would be impossible. I have used it in rare scenarios.

I usually go with `Pessimistic` locking (unless `Optimistic` is totally not an option). At the same time I would look of what hibernate generates for that query. For example you might need an `index` on how the entry is retrieved for the `DB` to actually lock *just the row* - because ultimately that is what you would want.